# How to use entitycollection for binding to wpf UI

Tags: wpf, data-binding, frameworks, entity

I'm using EntityFramework for data access and wpf as UI. If I bind WPF components to navigation properties of my entity classes(usually `EntityCollection<EntityClass>`, exposed as `IList<T>` in service layer), UI is not updating the changes. I know i have to use `ObservableCollection<T>` or such, but I need some guidance on how to use it without iterating back and forth upon save and retrieval processes.

(As you guessed, I'm new to WPF; so target your answers for a WPF beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use ObservableCollection. WPF actually depends upon INotifyCollectionChanged, which ObservableCollection implements. So if you create a wrapper collection which implements this interface and forwards the operations onto the EntityCollection and raises the events, you should be good (as long as you modify the collection via the wrapper and not the underlying collection. A similar concept is used for read-only collections (wrap an existing collection and interact with wrapper), simple Decorator pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use it directly (and have the changes be reflected).

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628437/best-practices-for-using-the-entity-framework-with-wpf-databinding) that explains how someone else solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in Silverlight LOB applications
I've created a silverlight library called ObservableCollections accompanied with visual studio 2012 addin and NUGet support, to generate the boilerplate code in order to wrap the EntityCollection with ObservableEntityCollection class, I know your question is about WPF but it could help.

http://observableec.codeplex.com/